# How do you do SIMD processing in python with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have two large 2D square `numpy` arrays of a length `N`.

I have a function that receives a row index for each array, operates on the respective rows and then places a single resultant vector in a third array.

My issue is that I would like to parallelize this function, however, I am not sure how to go about doing it. I've been taking a look at the `pool`-object in Python's `multiprocessing` library, but the data management is unclear to me.

From my current understanding, the **`pool.apply_async()`**-method receives an iterable and then splits it up for computation via individual processes. Would it be reasonable to feed it a list of tuples, where each element in a tuple is a row from one of the `numpy` arrays?

Or, is there a way for each process to load the arrays into memory a single time, and then continue to use those loaded arrays for each execution of the function? In this case, the iterable would again be a list of tuples, however each tuple would hold a pair of indexes for the arrays in memory, instead of the rows themselves.

Finally, is there any way that each process could submit the resultant vector into a single data object shared by all the workers, which I could then save?

Comment: Can you show the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each process to keep its own copy of the input arrays. But they cannot write to a shared output array; that's the whole point of using subprocesses rather than threads. (And in threads, the global interpreter lock will likely prevent threads from running concurrently anyway.)

In Linux (and probably MacOS as well), global variables that were initialized will be inherited by subprocesses with copy-on-write; as long as the subprocesses don't attempt to write, the variables will be using shared memory. In Windows, you have to initialize such global variables for each worker.

This is how to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

PERSISTENT_DATA = {}

def func(ij):
    i, j = ij
    return PERSISTENT_DATA['a'][i] + PERSISTENT_DATA['b'][j]

def init_persistent_data(a, b):
    PERSISTENT_DATA['a'] = a
    PERSISTENT_DATA['b'] = b

def run_parallel():
    n, m = 10, 5
    np.random.seed(1)
    a = np.random.randint(10, size=(n, m))
    b = np.random.randint(10, size=(n, m))
    
    # In Linux, these are inherited by the subprocesses.
    init_persistent_data(a, b)
    ij_tuples = [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
    
    # In Linux, leave the initializer and initargs out.
    with Pool(
        processes=4,
        initializer=init_persistent_data, 
        initargs=(a, b)
        ) as pl:
        result = pl.map(func, ij_tuples)
       
    result = np.array(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_parallel()
```